# Docker compose "--no-build was passed"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I try to `docker-compose up` with one of my images missing, I get:

```
Service 'server' needs to be built, but --no-build was passed.
```

I understand from the documentation that this is indeed what the `--no-build` option does:

> **--no-build**             Don't build an image, even if it's missing

Why is this default behavior and how can my `docker-compose up` automatically trigger a `docker-compose build` beforehand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is monitored by [issue 1679](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1679): "`docker-compose` up assumes `--no-build`"

The crux of the problem is:

> if my image exists (because I ran `docker-compose build` before), but the referred `Dockefile` changes, up won't trigger an automatic rebuild?
>   It may be a misunderstanding, but I thought that up always rebuilds the image if the Dockerfile is out of sync with the image, unless `--no-build` is passed.

[aanand](https://github.com/aanand) adds:

> `up` only checks that the image exists, not that it's up-to-date.
>   There's actually no way to check that.
>
> We've discussed alternative approaches, including [always building](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/12) and [never building](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/693).

Comment: Ok thanks! I'll follow up on that thread. I'm wondering though why there isn't simply a `--force-build` option just like there's a `--force-recreate` option ([reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/))..